# Apache mod rewrite, DirectorySlash Off root fix (seeing index of)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm very unfortunately stuck here.
I did a htaccess redirect for clean url. But whenever I had a path that corresponded to an existing directory, a backslash would be added which was very annoying and produced error in my script.

So I changed the DirectorySlash option to Off and it beautifully fixed my problem. Yes I am aware of the security warning and de-activated indexes.

Now my big problem is as follow: I cannot redirect to my index.php if the path to the website is entered WITHOUT the trailing slash because the REQUEST_URI is empty.

so,"www.my-website.com/" will work but "www.my-website.com" will not.

I thought to myself "well I'll just detect if the REQUEST is empty". nothing happens. Or mayble turn off directoryslash for subfolders only? 
After hours of searching, I found that the following did work but meant I had to write the url in hard and that really not optimal

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
  #prevent from weird bug if path is a directory
DirectorySlash Off

  # add the trailing slash to root directory
  # THIS IS WHERE I NEED A VARIABLE PATH THAT I DON'T NEED TO CHANGE MANUALY
RedirectMatch ^/?([^\.\/]+)$ http://my-fixed-url.com/$1/

  # Don't show directory indexes (the listing of files)
Options -Indexes -MultiViews

  # as long is it isn't an existing file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

  # Then redirect to index.php with the param "path" set to the url
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\_\-\/\.]+)$ index.php?path=$1 [QSA]
```

Any help is deeply appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Just change the `+` to a `*`, to also match this 'empty' url. So:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\_\-\/\.]*)$ index.php?path=$1 [QSA]
```

Comment: try just adding this rule at the end: `RewriteRule ^$ index.php?path=/`

Comment: no, absolutely nothing. Just as a reminder, DirectorySlash if Off